# REGEX extracting specific part non greedy

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, non-greedy

I'm new to Python 2.7.  Using regular expressions, I'm trying to extract from a text file just the emails from input lines.  I am using the non-greedy method as the emails are repeated 2 times in the same line.  Here is my code:

```
import re
f_hand = open('mail.txt')
for line in f_hand:
    line.rstrip()
    if re.findall('\S+@\S+?',line): print re.findall('\S+@\S+?',line)
```

however this is what i"m getting instead of just the email address:

```
['href="mailto:secretary@abc-mediaent.com">sercetary@a']
```

What shall I use in `re.findall` to get just the email out?

Comment: `[^@]+@\S+?`- match non-`@` explicitly.

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a HTML parser.

Comment: It would help to see an example of the text you're trying to parse, and what the expected output is.

Comment: Hi Brendan! this is the text :                                                                        <a href="mailto:sachin.gokhale@indiacast.com">sachin.gokhale@indiacast.com</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse a simple file with anchors for email addresses and always the same syntax (like double quotes to enclose attributes), you can use:

```
for line in f_hand: 
    print re.findall(r'href="mailto:([^"@]+@[^"]+)">\1</a>', line)
```

*(`re.findall` returns only the capture group. `\1` stands for the content of the first capture group.)*

If the file is a more complicated html file, use a parser, extract the links and filter them.
Or eventually use XPath, something like: 
`substring-after(//a/@href[starts-with(., "mailto:")], "mailto:")`

Answer (score 1):

try this
`re.findall('mailto:(\S+@\S+?\.\S+)\"',str))`

It should give you something like
`['secretary@abc-mediaent.com']`

Comment: hi Saurabh! this is what i'm getting now: ['mailto: email@email.com" ']   how can i remove the mailto and the " sign?

Answer (score 1):

`\S` means not a space. `"` and `>` are not spaces.

You should use `mailto:([^@]+@[^"]+)` as the regex (quoted form: `'mailto:([^@]+@[^"]+)'`). This will put the email address in the first capture group.

Answer (score 1):

\S accepts many characters that aren't valid in an e-mail address.  Try a regular expression of

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+
```

(presuming you are not trying to support Unicode -- it seems that you aren't since your input is a "text file").

This will require a "." in the server portion of the e-mail address, and your match will stop on the first character that is not valid within the e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format of an email address - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1.

Keeping that in mind the regex that you need is - `r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)"`. *(This works without having to depend on the text surrounding an email address.)*

The following lines of code -

```
html_str = r'<a href="mailto:sachin.gokhale@indiacast.com">sachin.gokhale@indiacast.com</a>'
email_regex = r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)"
print re.findall(email_regex, html_str)
```

yields -

```
['sachin.gokhale@indiacast.com', 'sachin.gokhale@indiacast.com']
```

P.S. - I got the regex for email addresses by googling for "*email address regex*" and clicking on the first site - http://emailregex.com/